# Terraform plugin crashed when provisioning the Azure Local Network Gateway

Tags: go, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying ti provision an `azure` local network gateway. When I try to `terraform apply` I get the following error:

> module.local_gateway.azurerm_local_network_gateway.local_gw: Creating...
> ╷
> │ Error: Plugin did not respond
> │
> │   with module.local_gateway.azurerm_local_network_gateway.local_gw,
> │   on modules/local-gateway/main.tf line 6, in resource "azurerm_local_network_gateway" "local_gw":
> │    6: resource "azurerm_local_network_gateway" "local_gw" {
> │
> │ The plugin encountered an error, and failed to respond to the plugin.(*GRPCProvider).ApplyResourceChange call. The plugin logs may contain more details.
> ╵

> Stack trace from the terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.0.0_x5 plugin:

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not string

> goroutine 104 [running]:
> github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/internal/services/network.expandLocalNetworkGatewayAddressSpaces(0x14001f87f00)
> /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/internal/services/network/local_network_gateway_resource.go:271 +0x234
> github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/internal/services/network.resourceLocalNetworkGatewayCreateUpdate(0x14001f87f00, {0x1081089a0, 0x14001f8dc00})
> /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/internal/services/network/local_network_gateway_resource.go:160 +0xa5c
> github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.(*Resource).create(0x14000dc6ee0, {0x108ae8b78, 0x14001cff880}, 0x14001f87f00, {0x1081089a0, 0x14001f8dc00})
> /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema/resource.go:329 +0x170
> github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.(*Resource).Apply(0x14000dc6ee0, {0x108ae8b78, 0x14001cff880}, 0x14001a63ba0, 0x14001f87d80, {0x1081089a0, 0x14001f8dc00})
> /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema/resource.go:467 +0x8d8
> github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.(*GRPCProviderServer).ApplyResourceChange(0x140004fa750, {0x108ae8b78, 0x14001cff880}, 0x14001d12dc0)
> /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema/grpc_provider.go:977 +0xe38
> github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go/tfprotov5/tf5server.(*server).ApplyResourceChange(0x14000237880, {0x108ae8c20, 0x14002009e30}, 0x14001c1ee00)
> /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go/tfprotov5/tf5server/server.go:603 +0x338
> github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go/tfprotov5/internal/tfplugin5._Provider_ApplyResourceChange_Handler({0x10864d540, 0x14000237880}, {0x108ae8c20, 0x14002009e30}, 0x14001a51020, 0x0)
> /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go/tfprotov5/internal/tfplugin5/tfplugin5_grpc.pb.go:380 +0x1c0
> google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC(0x140002a6fc0, {0x108b4df08, 0x14000448d80}, 0x14001a77680, 0x1400159c2a0, 0x10d0d0f40, 0x0)
> /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1292 +0xc04
> google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream(0x140002a6fc0, {0x108b4df08, 0x14000448d80}, 0x14001a77680, 0x0)
> /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1617 +0xa34
> google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2(0x1400156d0e0, 0x140002a6fc0, {0x108b4df08, 0x14000448d80}, 0x14001a77680)
> /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:940 +0x94
> created by google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1
> /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform->provider-azurerm/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:938 +0x1f0
> Error: The terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.0.0_x5 plugin crashed!
> This is always indicative of a bug within the plugin. It would be immensely
> helpful if you could report the crash with the plugin's maintainers so that it
> can be fixed. The output above should help diagnose the issue.

And here's my `local_gw.tf` code:

```
resource "azurerm_local_network_gateway" "local_gw" {
  name = var.azurerm_local_network_gateway_name

  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name

  gateway_address = var.gateway_address
  address_space   = var.local_gw_address_space # The gateway IP address to connect with
  tags            = merge(var.common_tags)
}
```

This is where it is being called as a module in `main.tf`

```
locals {
  azurerm_local_network_gateway_name = "local-gw"
  gateway_address = ""
  local_gw_address_space = [""]
  common_tags = {
    "environment"      = "test"
    "managedby"        = "devops"
    "developedby"      = "jananath"
  }
  project = "mysvg"
  resource_location = "Germany West Central"
}




# Local Gateway 
module "local_gateway" {
  source = "./modules/local-gateway"

  location                           = local.resource_location
  rg_name                            = var.rg_name
  azurerm_local_network_gateway_name = var.azurerm_local_network_gateway_name

  gateway_address        = var.gateway_address
  local_gw_address_space = var.local_gw_address_space

  common_tags = merge(
    local.common_tags,
    {
      "Name" = "${local.project}-${var.azurerm_local_network_gateway_name}"
    },
  )
}
```

This is my `provider.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
    backend "azurerm" {
        resource_group_name  = "shared-resources"
        storage_account_name = "janasvtfstate"
        container_name       = "tfstate"
        key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
    }

}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The multiple declarations of module “local_gateway” caused this problem. here is no need to declare the items again in the main TF file. As shown below, simply declaring a module suffices.

```
  module "local_gateway" {
      source = "./modules/local_gw/"
    }
```

*Variables are defined directly on the code in the updated code snippet below.*

**Step1:

main tf code as follows**

```
locals {
  azurerm_local_network_gateway_name = "local-gw"
  gateway_address = ""
  local_gw_address_space = [""]
  common_tags = {
    "environment"      = "test"
    "managedby"        = "devops"
    "developedby"      = "jananath"
  }
  project = "mysvg"
  resource_location = "Germany West Central"
}
module "local_gateway" {
  source = "./modules/local_gw/"
}
```

**Module ->local_gw->local_gw tf code as follows**

```
resource "azurerm_local_network_gateway" "local_gw" {
  name = "localgatewayswarnademo"
  location            = "Germany West Central"
  resource_group_name = "rg-swarnademonew"
   gateway_address     = "12.13.14.15"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  tags            = merge("demo")
}
```

**Provider tf file code as**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
    # backend "azurerm" {
    #     resource_group_name  = "shared-resources"
    #     storage_account_name = "janasvtfstate"
    #     container_name       = "tfstate"
    #     key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
    # }

}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

**Note: Commented on the storage account. If required, create it manually.**

**Step2: run below commands**

```
terraform plan
```

plan output
[image]

```
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

Apply output
[image]

**Verification from portal.**

Output:
[image]